# Добавление списков в mysql

Tags: python-3.x, циклы, списки

Есть ряд списков:
Короткая ссылка:

```
['https://youtu.be/grJzOKqFBVA', 'https://youtu.be/rCbeIFsx6fc', 'https://youtu.be/cI4WNUNg0sM', 'https://youtu.be/yEeuH1JysHc', 'https://youtu.be/c5mHm6C0EQA']
Дата публикации: ['2018-03-22T21:05:51.000Z', '2018-03-22T18:14:07.000Z', '2018-03-22T14:43:41.000Z', '2018-03-22T14:38:32.000Z', '2018-03-22T14:38:14.000Z']
Название видео: ['Astralis vs Godsent ECS Season 5 Europe', 'EnVyUs vs GODSENT ECS Season 5 Europe', 'AGO vs Spirit, StarLadder ImbaTV Invitational Chongqing', 'Flash vs Spirit, StarLadder ImbaTV Invitational Chongqing', 'TyLoo vs MVP PK, StarLadder ImbaTV Invitational Chongqing']
Описание видео: ['Запись матча турнира ECS Season 5 Europe. Делай ставки на ECS Season 5 – Подписывайся на наш контент-канал:...', 'Запись матча турнира ECS Season 5 Europe. Делай ставки на ECS Season 5 – Подписывайся на наш контент-канал:...', 'Запись матча между AGO и Spirit в рамках турнира StarLadder ImbaTV Invitational Chongqing. Подписывайся на наш контент-канал: ', 'Запись матча между Flash и Spirit в рамках турнира StarLadder ImbaTV Invitational Chongqing. Подписывайся на наш контент-канал:...', 'Запись матча между TyLoo и MVP PK в рамках турнира StarLadder ImbaTV Invitational Chongqing. Подписывайся на наш контент-канал:...']
```

Необходимо добавить в mysql эти значения. В первую строку - первые значения, во вторую строку таблицы mysql - вторые и т.д. В идеале кол-во значений в списках определяется переменной, в крайнем случае фиксированное кол-во будет норм

Comment: в чём у вас сложности? Установлена ли база данных? Можете ли вы к ней подключиться? Схема базы данных у вас есть? Существуют нужные таблицы? или вы не знаете какую схему можно использовать? Если схему знаете, нужна ли помощь с созданием нужных таблиц? Какую ORM вы используете? Или вы хотите с помощью sql? какие конкретно проблемы с тем как вставить значения? Ясно ли как sql insert запрос написать? Попробуйте обновить вопрос и сузить его до конкретной проблемы, подробней описав ваше окружение и место где вы застряли

Comment: Установлена ли база данных? - Да. Можете ли вы к ней подключиться? - Да. Схема базы данных у вас есть? - Да. Существуют нужные таблицы? - Да. вы не знаете какую схему можно использовать? Схему таблицы знаю. Какую ORM вы используете? Не уверен, что понял вопрос. Или вы хотите с помощью sql? - Да.  какие конкретно проблемы с тем как вставить значения? Проблема в том, что кол-во значений заранее неизвестно. Нужно написать цикл, который будет проходить сначала брать первое значение, потом второе и т.д. Я думал как-то через [i]. После каждой итерации прибавлять 1.

Comment: связанный вопрос [How can I use executemany to insert into MySQL a list of dictionaries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18244565/4279)

Comment: если у вас есть рабочее выражение `db.execute('insert into...',  tuples[i])`, то просто на `db.executemany('insert into...', tuples)` замените.